# How to get Telerik's RadEditor's Spell checker to start automatically when incorrect word is typed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Currently I have to click the Spell check button on RadEditor's toolbar to see the word suggestions. Is there any way for that? I did find a way to run Spell Checker on Submit Button click but how do I get what I want? I have gone through forums but in vain. Need help please. Thanks

Telerik people have not replied. It's been three days now so asking here. Anybody who is familiar with Telerik controls please help me out.

**edit:
Anybody in here who is familiar with Telerik controls please help me out.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way for the spellchecker to check each word right after you type it - you have to click the spell tool (or you can assign a keyboard shortcut for it). By the way - all modern browsers except IE already offer built-in spellcheck support that is available inside the RadEditor as well - you can try it by opening a RadEditor page with Firefox, Chrome, etc. - [RadEditor demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx). Just start typing and the incorrect words will be marked.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this solution, it took a time interval after stop typing:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    //setup before auto spellchecking functions 
    var typingTimer;                //timer identifier 
    var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 2 second for example

function InitializeRadEditor() {
        var editor = $find("<%= RadEditor1.ClientID %>");

        //  Getting a reference to content area and attach events to it
        var myInput = editor.get_contentArea();

        myInput.attachEvent("onkeyup", Func_onkeyup);
        myInput.attachEvent("onkeydown", Func_onkeydown);
    }

//  RadEdit content area event function
    function Func_onkeyup() {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    //  RadEdit content area event function
    function Func_onkeydown() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    }  

//user is "finished typing," fire the spellchecker
    function doneTyping() {
        var editor = $find("<%= RadEditor1.ClientID %>");
        if (editor.get_text() != "") {
            editor.fire("AjaxSpellCheck"); //fire the spellchecker "Or any name in your tools.xml file , that related to SpellCheck"
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>

<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" SkinID="DefaultSetOfTools"   Height="515"
 OnClientLoad="InitializeRadEditor" EditModes="Design,Preview" Width="680" DialogHandlerUrl="~/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd"
  ToolsFile="~/ToolsFile.xml"></telerik:RadEditor>
```